# Purely algebraic proof of the constancy of algebraic de Rham cohomology in smooth families over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $f: X \to S$ is a smooth, proper morphism of nonsingular complex algebraic varieties with $S$ connected, then the dimensions of the (algebraic) de Rham cohomology groups of the fibers of $f$ are constant.  One way to see this is to use that, complex analytically, $f$ is a locally trivial fibration (Ehresmann's theorem), hence all fibers are homeomorphic, and to conclude by using the topological invariance of analytic de Rham cohomology and the comparison between algebraic and analytic de Rham cohomology.

Is there a 'purely algebraic' proof of this result, i.e. one which does not appeal to GAGA and Ehresmann's theorem?

Comment: By smoothness, the de Rham cohomology groups carry canonical connections called the Gauß–Manin connection. It follows that they are locally free, 2.5.2.1 of [Yves André, *Différentielles non commutatives et théorie de Galois différentielle ou aux différences*](http://www.numdam.org/articles/10.1016/s0012-9593(01)01074-6/).

Comment: You can use Deligne-Illusie to prove the degeneration of the Hodge-de Rham spectral sequence.

Comment: . . . By vanishing theorems (also proved algebraically by Deligne-Illusie), the coherent sheaf cohomology groups arising in that spectral sequence are locally constant.  Thus, also the de Rham cohomology groups are locally constant.

Comment: @Z.M thanks.  What is the argument for the existence of the Gauss-Manin connection in characteristic 0?  I thought this involved something like Ehresmann's theorem.

Comment: @JasonStarr thank you.  Could you elaborate on the relation between vanishing theorems and local constancy of the de Rham cohomology of the fibers?

Comment: The Gauß–Manin connection is covered in N. M. Katz and T. Oda, *On the differentiation of de Rham cohomology classes with respect to parameters*, J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 8 (1968), 199–213; MR 237510. A derived version can be found in Guo, H., & Li, S. (2021). *Period sheaves via derived de Rham cohomology*. Compositio Mathematica, 157(11), 2377-2406. doi:10.1112/S0010437X21007545

Comment: @Z.M In Yves André's paper, I think 2.5.2.2 would be a better reference.